# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'detectMultiScale'

Tags: python, opencv, attributeerror, object-detection

This is the code

```
import cv2, sys
from numpy import array
img = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
img2 = array( 200  * (img[:,:,2] > img[:,:, 1]), dtype='uint8')
objects = cv2.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(img2)
print (objects)
```

I have the error in the title at line 5. (I have tried also with `cv2.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(img)` and I have the same error).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function `detectMultiScale()` on an instance of `CascadeClassifier()`

```
cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier()
objects = cascade.detectMultiScale(img2)
```